# Liquid templating get tokens in a custom block

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, redcarpet

I am trying to build custom block using the [Liquid Templating](https://github.com/Shopify).
Following is my code:

```
module MyModule
    module Blocks
        class MyBlock < Liquid::Block

            def initialize(tag, markup, tokens)
                super
                @tag = tag
                @tokens = tokens
                @markup = markup
            end

            def render(context)
                p @tokens
            end

        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('myblock', MyModule::Blocks::MyBlock)
```

And in my template, I have the following code:

```
{% for i in mypages %}
    {% myblock %} {{ i.title }} {% endmyblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how do I get all the content that is passed between the `myblock` tags. i.e., how do I make `i.title` available to `myblock`'s `render` function. I thought `tokens` captures this, but when I `puts tokens` it outputs `[]`

Thank You

Comment: I've not got the answer here ,but in terms of debugging it, extract `{% myblock %}....` out of the `for` loop and put it straight into the post/page, with a static value: `{% myblock %} this is my block {% endmyblock %}` . This way you know what you should expect for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` method of `Liquid::Block` returns the text between the begin and end tags. So just change your render method to this:

```
def render(context)
  p super
end
```